# Why aren't my labels displaying in my collection view cells?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set up a collection view programmatically with my views in separate files. It seems that the labels I'm making are not being displayed in the collection view cells. The cells seem fine, and the data that should be in the cells does exist, but it just isn't showing up.

Here's a link to my full project for reference: https://github.com/bronsonmullens/RPG-Dice-Roller/tree/master/RPG%20Dice%20Roller/RPG%20Dice%20Roller

This is my first post on stackoverflow - sorry if the formatting might be off.

Comment: Instead of simply giving the link to your project, try pasting the relevant code here to show your work. Refer this link for details https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I felt like it was a little bit too much code. I'll do it anyways next time then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
class DiceLabel: UILabel {
    let diceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        // ... configure `label` here ...
        return label
    }()
}
```

That's pointless and nonsense. You are giving your label *another* label as a property, and it does nothing for the display of *your* label, the DiceLabel. Hence your use of DiceLabel is all wrong, because it's just a plain UILabel with no properties set. None of your configurations have any effect. You mean this:

```
class DiceLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // ... configure `self` here ...
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was on the right track for my cell, but I had no idea what I was thinking for the label. Maybe I'll pick up your book..

Comment: Yes in general I really liked your code organization.